# Can ownership of a solidity contract be relinquished?

Tags: solidity, security

I'd like to maintain ownership of a set of contracts for a period of time to build them out, but eventually I'd like to relinquish ownership so that the users don't have to trust me to not steal their ethers. My idea is to just set the owner to address 0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111 like so:

```
function relinquishOwnership() onlyOwner {
    owner = 0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111;
}
```

Is it safe to assume that nobody owns this address? And is this a safe way of ensuring that nobody has ownership of the contract? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: ```
function relinquishOwnership() onlyOwner { owner = address(0);
} ```
How about this ?

Comment: That's probably the way to go, not sure why I wanted to use 0x111.... It was probably a way of asking if 0x111... would work as well as address(0) but I can't recall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot know if an address is owned or not, or will be owned in the future. So I think this approach will not lead to what you want.

Instead I would suggest to introduce a way to turn the ownership feature off.

- Add a new variable, `bool ownershipEnabled`for example, to your contract.
- Add a modifier that allows execution of a function if `ownershipEnabled`is set to true and use it with your functions that can be carried out by the owner only. Alternatively you could modify your `onlyOwner`modifier accordingly.
- Once you want to relinquish ownership, you call a function that sets`ownershipEnabled` to false.

If you don't include a function to set `ownershipEnabled` to true, your ownership feature can never again be turned on.

Comment: Ah good idea, I didn't think of that! I would imagine the probability of somebody owning an address of such low entropy would be very low, but yours is still a better/safer solution.